# Bootstrap modal and Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, crud

I want a Bootstrap modal (underscore template: `dialog-template`) to show when clicking `#add-button` (create new task) or `.list-group-item-heading` (edit existing task), but the modal won't appear, even though the modal html is appended to the body.

My attempt is here: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0a3cwvct/).

*(As my REST API is not available to the jsfiddle, the task list is empty, I don't know if there's any way to fix this with jsfiddle?)*

Comment: Is the render function called at all?

Comment: @meskobalazs It is called through the `edit` function, which is in turn triggered when `.list-group-item-heading` is clicked.

Comment: So, if it is called, then it should append it to the DOM. Does it append it? If so, you might need to manually show the modal: `$('.modal-dialog').modal('show')`

Comment: @meskobalazs Yes, it puts the modal html before the end of the <body> but the modal is **not** rendered. Note: the code is updated, I have just inserted a initialize function in the `TaskDialog` view that specifies the template to remove an error.

Comment: By rendered I meant that the modal is not shown, but obviously the html is there.

Comment: Yes, I understood that :) Does the `.modal('show')` work?

Comment: @meskobalazs Do you suggest that the `show()` function should have: `$(document.body).append(this.render().el).modal("show");`? If I do that, the background get dimmed, but the modal is still **not** show.

Comment: The dialog still has the `hide` class?

Comment: @meskobalazs I removed the `hide` class from the template, but it does the same as before.

Comment: Well, I can't really help any further without a jsfiddle, or something similar, but as you can see, it must be some problem with your CSS classes.

Comment: @meskobalazs I have added a jsfiddle to the question. However my REST api is not available there so the tasks list is empty and I don't know how to fix that with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your Fiddle and fixing its dependency issues, there are a couple problems:

1. Your Add button has no idea what modal its attribute is referring to, since the **modal exists as a Backbone View with a template, and is not in the DOM**.
2. Your Add modal has no model to render with, and `this.$el.modal()` is never called.

To fix this, your button must have a click handler for initializing and rendering a modal, and your modal must create a new Task if it doesn't already have one. Then it just needs to call the Bootstrap `modal` function. I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0a3cwvct/1/) to reflect this.

All I did was fix the problems above. I'm leaving it up to you to figure out the communication between the modal's model getting into the Task Collection upon a save.

Comment: In your definition of `Button` why do you enclose it in parantheses, and why the `()` at the end? Why do you make it a `new` and not just `var Button = Backbone.View.extend({...});`?

Comment: It's essentially the same, except that since it's highly unlikely that view will ever be used again, that makes the view singleton and saves me from having to create an instance of it.

Comment: It actually should have been `button` and not `Button` because it's not a class definition - it's an instance of an anonymous class.